# Delete word and preceding whitespace

Tags: vim, removing-whitespace

When I edit a text, I often find myself removing one word from an existing sentence. I use `diw` for this, the problem is only, between the surrounding words of the just deleted word will remain two whitespaces, the one before and the one after the just deleted word. Is there an easy trick to remove a word and all preceding whitespaces?

I want to achieve this:

```
This is just an example
```

to

```
This is an example
```

With `diw` I am always left with

```
This is  an example
```

Maybe there is a cool trick I haven't found yet!

Comment: Would probably be better asked (if it hasn't already been) at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `diw` deletes *inside* a word. You can also delete *around* a word with `daw`.

You can find more information about those here: `:help aw`.